# Breeze.Angular.Q 1.0.0 Setup

Tags: angularjs, breeze

I followed the directions on [BreezeJS Angular Q](http://www.breezejs.com/breeze-labs/breezeangularqjs) to "Install this module", however I receive an error on the fail() callback when making a dataservice call. When using Q.js, there was no problem.

error:

```
Object #<Object> has no method 'fail'
```

dataservice call:

```
dataservice.getAllEntities($scope.includeName, false, i, takeNum)
.then(querySucceeded)
.fail(queryFailed);
```

What could be up with my setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to pass the fail callback as the second parameter to `then`,

I see `Q` should have that `.fail()` shorthand, but it's probably better to just use the standard `.then()` notation:

From that page:

```
.then(successCallback, failCallback);
```

So your code should be like:

```
dataservice.getAllEntities($scope.includeName, false, i, takeNum)
.then(querySucceeded, queryFailed);
```

I'm not really sure why `.fail` doesn't exist though..